# Restore List Workflow in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

We have created a List workflow in SharePoint 2010 associated with List-X. Mistakenly, someone has deleted the List-X and it is not even available in Recyclebin.

Now, How could we reassociated the workflow? Should we create a new List with that name and try to reassociated using SharePoint designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new list exactly like the deleted one. Once created, in SPDesigner go to Lists and Libraries > your new list > make note of the List ID.

In SharePoint Designer, go to All Files > Workflows and find the orphan workflow.
Edit in advanced mode the `.xoml.wfconfig.xml` file.

Find the attribute `<Association ListID=` and replace the current GUID with the GUID of the newly created List.

**Close SPDesigner, then reopen it.**
Go to the list and your workflow should be there.

Comment: This is correct.  This also works if you are restoring a backup of a site to a new location.  A couple of additional steps may be necessary based on your particular scenerio.   1)  You may need to manually set your task list and history list using SharePoint Designer.  2)  You may have broken references in the workflow itself.  If you do, certain steps will contain GUIDS rather than list/field names.  If this is the case, you can either fix by hand via SPD, or mass fix by going into the .xoml file for your workflow and doing mass find/replaces with the old-GUID/new-GUID pairs.